# How can I make function print more results?

Tags: python, tuples, divmod

so I've been for a couple of hours now trying to do this test and I wanted to produce a very concatenated way to my result using a Tuple and the divmod function, and I finally got to a solution..
But I can't understand why it only prints 1 result instead of multiple..
here is my code:

```
def tilt(money):
     amount = [(1,'dollar'),(0.25,'quarter'),(0.10,'dime'),(0.05,'nickel'),(0.01,'pennie')]
     total = {}
     for amount_value, amount_name in amount:
         if money >= amount_value:
             number_amount, money = divmod(money, amount_value)
             total[amount_name] = number_amount
     return total

    print(tilt(10.65))

# result for this is {'dollar': 10.0}

# what I expect is {'dollar': 10, 'quarter': 2, 'dime': 1, 'nickel': 1}
```

I just cant wrap my head around a solution, and I would like to avoid going in an endless If-Else code to get to this point.
I'm sure there must be a simple solution that I'm missing, thanks in advance for your help..

Comment: Please update your question with the correct indentation. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: sorry for that, i just updated it, is it better?

Comment: No, this code would fail with an IndentationError as well.

Comment: It appears that you need to repeat a tutorial on dicts, to learn how to add new entries.

Comment: sorry for my mistakes, I'm still learning. Should i delete this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment; But it's probably down to your indentation. If you put your return statement in line with your for loop - you'll get the response you're looking for.

so that it is as follows:

```
def tilt(money):
    amount = [(1, 'dollar'), (0.25, 'quarter'), (0.10, 'dime'),
              (0.05, 'nickel'), (0.01, 'pennie')]
    total = {}
    for amount_value, amount_name in amount:
        if money >= amount_value:
            number_amount, money = divmod(money, amount_value)
            total[amount_name] = number_amount
    return total
```

Comment: well OMG i've been scratching my head for so long, and I always had it right!
BIG thanks!

Comment: Seems like you loose a penny with `tilt(1.43)` Floats may not be the best choice here.

Comment: Indentation is really important in python- if you're just starting out with python pay extra care when indenting your code.

Comment: yes i just realize I'm missing a penny cant understand why...

Comment: Please see https://0.30000000000000004.com/